# Не выводит элемент MsgBox()

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Почему у меня не выводит элемент MsgBox(), ошибок не выдаёт во время компиляции, но при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит. Также пробовал без объявления "msg" и присваивания, тоже ничего не получилось.

Почему этот элемент не корректно работает?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        'Dim i, s, m As Integer
        Dim msg As Boolean
        'm = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        'Dim N(m) As Integer
        's = 0
        msg = MsgBox("Текст содержащий вопрос", vbYesNo, "Диалоговоя форма")
        'For i = 1 To m
        'ListBox1.Items.Add(Str(i))
        'N(i) = i
        's = +N(i)
        'Next
        'ListBox1.Items.Add("S = " + Str(s))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Такие комментарии можно было бы и удалить..

Comment: Вы случайно не отвязали событие от кнопки?

Comment: Вы не про то что должно быть в скобках: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Comment: Если скобки заполнены то работает, но теперь что написано в скобках и как оно связывает кнопку с формой?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых MsgBox возвращает число но не Boolean.

Попробуйте так, взято из рабочей проги:

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to enter a new patient?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
' do something
End If
```